# findRecord in Google CloudDatastore with Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I want to use Objectify to query Google Cloud Datastore. What is an appropriate way to find a record based on a known key-value pair? The record is in the database, I verified this by Google's Datastore viewer.

Here is my method stub, which triggers the NotFoundException:

```
@ApiMethod(name="getUser")
public User getUser() throws NotFoundException {
    String filterKey = "googleId";
    String filterVal = "jochen.bauer@gmail.com";
    User user = OfyService.ofy().load().type(User.class).filter(filterKey, filterVal).first().now();
    if (user == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException("User Record does not exist");
    }
    return user;
}
```

Here is the User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
Long id;
private HealthVault healthVault;
private String googleId;

public User(String googleId){
    this.googleId = googleId;
    this.healthVault = new HealthVault();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public HealthVault getHealthVault() {
    return healthVault;
}
public void setHealthVault(HealthVault healthVault) {
    this.healthVault = healthVault;
}
public String getGoogleId() {
    return googleId;
}
public void setGoogleId(String googleId) {
    this.googleId = googleId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it fails because of transaction. You need to make a transctionless call like:

```
User user = OfyService.ofy().transactionless().load().type(User.class).filter(filterKey, filterVal).first().now();
```

More info about transactions on App Engine:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions
https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions

EDIT
Your object needs @Index annotation. It will add field to datastore index. Only properties that are in the index can be searchable. Filter method is one of them.

```
@Id
Long id;
@Index
private HealthVault healthVault;
@Index
private String googleId;
```

P.S. delete your object with googleId jochen.bauer@gmail.com and write it again to database after you updated your entity. And objectify will find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately adding transactionless() to my query did not solve this.

Comment: Show your User object.

Comment: Thanks - the key was to delete the old entity!

Answer (score 0):

First add `@Index` in your fields model. I didn't see `filterVal` as an email in your model. Even so, to get the entity based in your `filterVal` assuming that is `googleId` is the field of your entity.

```
User user = OfyService.ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("googleId", filterVal).now();
```

And so if your `filterKey` is the id of your entity.

```
User user = OfyService.ofy().load().key(Key.create(User.class, filterKey)).now();
```